# How can I create an array of imported images in a React Component?

Tags: reactjs, image, components

I have a React component that will have nearly a hundred images, and so want to load them via one import statement from another JavaScript file.

But first I need to figure out how to put them all in an array somehow so I can export them from that JavaScript file.

Is something like this possible:

[image]

So I can access the images like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bulkImages.js** v1 (your way is possible)

```
import image1 from './images/image1.jpg'
import image2 from './images/image2.jpg'
import image3 from './images/image3.jpg'
import image4 from './images/image4.jpg'
import image5 from './images/image5.jpg'


const bulkImages = [
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4,
  image5,
];

export default bulkImages;
```

**bulkImages.js** v2 (but this version is shorter)

```
const bulkImages = [
  './images/image1.jpg',
  './images/image2.jpg',
  './images/image3.jpg',
  './images/image4.jpg',
  './images/image5.jpg'
];

export default bulkImages;
```

To display images from **array** in your component use the **map()** function.

**YourComponent.js**

```
import React from 'react';

// images data
import bulkImages from './bulkImages';

export default function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <div className="bulkImageArea">
      {bulkImages.map((img) => (
        <img key={img} src={img} alt={img} className="bulkImage" />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```